# Should I make an Index for an extremely dynamic column in terms of distinct values it has

Tags: sql, indexing

Is it a good practice to make a non-clustered index on a created_on column.
Everyday on an average the table is updated with 4000 entries.
For each entry the value of this column will be different, since it is a time stamp.
Is it preferable to index such columns? Please advice.

---

It would be great if you could elaborate the impact of creating an index on a volatile field(one that has too many distinct values) as compared to a column which has limited number of distinct entries.

Comment: Not unless you have a **specific** performance measurement that **proves** that this index would be beneficial. Too many indexes is worse than none! Don't over-index - use indexes sparingly - only if you can be sure they'll help ....

Answer (score 0):

If you must use that column (often) in queries then you can index it as it will boost the performance of the query. If that column will not be used in queries then there's no reason to index it.

Answer (score 0):

Index columns based on how they are interrogated, not written. If you search (WHERE), sort (ORDER BY) or group (GROUP BY) on that column then you probably want an index. If it's only for sort however, I recommend you sort by your ID field instead, assuming you have one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It would be great if you could elaborate the impact of creating an index on a volatile field(one that has too many distinct values) as compared to a column which has limited number of distinct entries.

Comment: Using an index on a field which has a high number of unique values is normal. A primary key is exactly that!

Comment: Agreed. But primary key(i.e. clustered index) is the table itself re-organised in the form of a B Tree. At the nodes we have the  physical rows.
That is not the case for a non-clustered index. It stores the pointer to rows.
My query is regarding a non-clustered index.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but you're not clear about what you want to know. Will it speed up a where/order/ group based on that column? Yes. Will it increase the size of your index? Yes. If you don't use an index for these things in a large data set, on a query that is used regularly then you're asking for trouble. Care to clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks :)
Actually I am not really into a scenario where I would want an index on created_at. The question was out of curiosity to know the fact how such indices impact the RAM space and other impacts. Wanted to know whether an index with too many distinct values in column would consume more space in RAM compared to those with fewer distinct values.

Comment: It's going to reduce RAM usage as the indexes are stored on disk and make computation easier / faster.